# How should I allow my visual studio code extension to debug .jsonc files and allow the user to set breakpoints?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I'm developing an extension that should be able to open .jsonc files and put breakpoints on the file that are latter used with a custom debug adapter.
But when the extension is in test mode with a .jsonc opened the VSCode UI is not able to add breakpoints by clicking where we usually does and even the right click menu for handling breakpoints is not shown.
I could open .json files and set breakpoints there but not to .jsonc files. Even though the package.json is configured in the same way for .json than for .jsonc files.

I configured the extension with package.json :

```
"activationEvents": [
"onDebugResolve:jsondebug",
"onDebugDynamicConfigurations:jsondebug",
"onCommand:extension.json-debug.getProgramName",
```

],

```
"breakpoints": [
  {
    "language": "jsonc"
  },
  {
    "language": "json"
  }
],
```

and

```
"debuggers": [
  {
    "type": "my-debugger",
    "languages": [
      "json",
      "jsonc"
    ],
  }
 ]
```

All of this works for .json files but not for .jsonc files.
What I'm missing. Maybe there are more specific code at debugger activation?

Comment: what is debuggable in a JSON file, give an example file

Comment: JSON with a schema that allows IF-THEN such as: `{ "if": { "compare": "$var1", "==": "10" }, "then" : { "set": "#var2", "value": "20" } }`

Comment: would it be a lot easier if you translate that to a Python file, a lot more readable